# Can I do these using Code Coverage with Cobertura

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I am just looking at the cobertura maven plugin and I wasnt sure if the following is possible

1. Instrument classes
2. Run junit tests
3. Generate Cobertura report without reinstrumenting classes and running tests

I have a multi module maven project and the coverage of the domain module is showing up as 0% even though its been used by every other module
I have tried different combinations of things but the coverage of my domain module always stays at 0%.
People have mentioned writing separate tests for the domain classes but i dont want to do this as you could easily write a tests to test a function that isn't actually being used anywhere within the codebase

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your title "Code Coverage with Cobertura" is not very specific -- you may want to change it to reflect the multi module maven problem if that is your key question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so you would have to execute the maven goals in the correct order so :

```
    cobertura:instrument 
    test
    goalToAskCoberturaToGenerateReport
```

But then comes the trouble : there is no such goal as cobertura:report, if you look at the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) and [source code](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/cobertura-maven-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura/CoberturaReportMojo.java) of the maven plugin : The goal cobertura:cobertura is the only goal generating the report. I suspect it is as such because of some maven internal limitation.

So in short, given the state of the maven plugin it is not possible.

You might have a chance to manage what you want to achieve by executing cobertura from the command line.

Comment: yes I was looking at that and noticed the same thing about the reports. I may look at using jacaco or clover or some other alternative

Answer (score 0):

For multi-module maven projects cross-module coverage seems not to be available off-the-shelf with Cobertura.

A solution using a mixture of maven and ant is described byThomas Sundberg:
http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/test-coverage-in-a-multi-module-maven-project/

See also this related question:
[Maven2 Multiproject Cobertura Reporting Problems During mvn site Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94556/maven2-multiproject-cobertura-reporting-problems-during-mvn-site-build/16494633#16494633)